# property Values are not replace with actual values in soapUI

Tags: excel, groovy, soapui

I am trying to fetch data from excel file and try to run that data in SoapUI using groovy script. and storing request response in excel file.
Everything is working fine.I am using properties  to pass request from groovy script to soapUI request. in excel it is storing request as it is. not replacing it with values.GetInfoByZIP is my request name

Here is my groovy script:

```
Label label1 = new Label(i+1,j+1,context.testCase.getTestStepByName("GetInfoByZIP").getProperty("request").value)
log.info label
sheet1.addCell(label);
sheet1.addCell(label1)
log.info j+" " +i+" "+"  "+response
}

}
workbook1.write()
workbook1.close()
```

My Soap Request:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:web="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <web:GetInfoByZIP>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <web:USZip>${Properties#zip}</web:USZip>
      </web:GetInfoByZIP>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

here properties is my property name.

Comment: Please read about [mcve].

Comment: edited please see once

Comment: try this
def request = context.expand( '${GetInfoByZIP#Request}' )
Label label1 = new Label(i+1,j+1,request)

Comment: Thanks it worked:)